# Conversion type

Tags: vb.net

Here is my condition

i retrieve a datetime data from the database and store it into string type in my application. From the string type i need to convert it to date in order to print a receipt.

My data is "31/12'2012". I wanted to convert it to date only without the time(DateTime()). This aapcation has been done by programmer before me with no problem but now i face this probem reocurring again and again.

My last problem with this is when i ignore the the converting problem and instead print the string as it is from the database i instead receive a "dd/mm/yy" instead of the date iteself. May i know where do i go wrong here?

Comment: "store it into string type in my application" - that's the start of your issues - try to keep data that has a well defined type (such as datetime) as that type, rather than treating it as a string, for as long as possible. Only convert it to a string during output.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse("31/12/2012").ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: i try your way but it still said string cannot be converted to date Dim Expire = DirectCast(sExpiryDate, DateTime).ToShortDateString(). sExpiryDate is the string where i store my date from the database into the string

Comment: @NgYangYang Sorry, I thought that there was a typo in your date. Is it actually `31/12'2012`, because if it is then that is an invalid date.

Comment: there is no typo mistake in my coding. Just some error typing here

Comment: @NgYangYang So your value is infact `31/12/2012` not `31/12'2012`?

Comment: yeah so back to this problem. i wanted to ignore the date and just print out the date but coud'nt. Now want to convert my string type to date i have no idea how in vb.net 2008. When i didnt convert it to string type in the first place, the program woudnt let me do so.

Comment: Dim Expire = DateTime.Parse("31/12/2012").ToShortDateString(). So i do it like this and my "Expire" variable now is a DateTime type?

Comment: @NgYangYang no, it would be a string but just the date. If you want it as a `DateTime` type then don't call `.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: Even if it shows only date, how do i convert from string to date still?

Comment: As I just said, lose the `ToShortDateString()`, which would be this: `Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(val)`.